# Potential reason why vc-annotate output is sometimes incomplete?

Tags: version-control, vc

On Emacs 27.1 running on Linux, with Subversion backend, `vc-annotate` does not always annotate the complete file (seen on 3000-lines, 110KB text file).  The vc-annotate-mode buffer holds the beginning of the annotation but stops before the end of the file.

The `svn annotate` command issued inside a shell-mode buffer returns the annotation of all file lines without any problem.

I just started seeing this but that problem, but aside from rebooting Linux recently nothing changed.

Has anyone seen this problem?  Is there some config variable that can be changed to help?  Perhaps a byte-size limit somewhere?

I'v been using vc-annotate with Subversion, Mercurial and Git backend without problem in the past and can't see what would have changed.

The rendering inside an Emacs buffer always stop before 64K  for the point (65535).  As if something is limiting the rendering in terms of size.  Any idea what that could be?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you see anything different from the command line? (I.e. without Emacs)

Comment: @phils:  Inside or outside of emacs, using the svn annotate command on the file always gets all lines for the file where I see the problem.  ie: I never see the problem on the command line.

Comment: I continue to see this problem and the rendering inside an Emacs buffer pretty much always stops around and before 64K bytes of the file, as if there was a limit in size somewhere.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: @phils, finally created https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=59232